# Clang Profiling with Instrumentation on Android

Tags: android, c++, clang, profiling

I'm compiling a shared library for Android, that someone else loads in their app. I want to profile my library as it runs on an Android device, using Clang's [profiling with instrumentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#profiling-with-instrumentation).

I've added the Clang option `-fprofile-instr-generate` to compilation and linkage, and though this produces raw profiling data when the library is compiled and loaded on Linux, on Android I get the following error:

> 04-26 20:39:37.559  3313  3313 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>
> 04-26 20:39:37.559  3313  3313 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 04-26 20:39:37.559  3313  3313 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.my.process, PID: 3313
>
> 04-26 20:39:37.559  3313  3313 E AndroidRuntime:
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__start___llvm_prf_vnds" referenced by "/path/to/my.so"...
>
> 04-26 20:39:37.559  3313  3313 E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
>
> 04-26 20:39:37.559  3313  3313 E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)

When running `nm -D my.so | grep prf` I get:

> 00000000007f1cc8 d __start___llvm_prf_cnts
>
> 0000000000827918 d __start___llvm_prf_data
>
> 00000000008fb570 d __start___llvm_prf_names
>
> 000000000117bf58 d __start___llvm_prf_vnds
>
> 0000000000827918 a __stop___llvm_prf_cnts
>
> 00000000008fb568 a __stop___llvm_prf_data
>
> 000000000117bf54 a __stop___llvm_prf_names
>
> 0000000001181f58 a __stop___llvm_prf_vnds

So it looks like the symbols are there.

Is it possible to run the profiling instrumentation on Android?

Comment: Hi, I'm currently dealing with this kind of error, did you resolved this? Could you please share your insights :) Thanks

Comment: Hej! Unfortunately no, I never got the instrumentation to work. But I did get the perf tool in the sdk to work, where you run it from computer with adb connected (with wire or over wifi) and put in the process ID. It wasn't immediate though...

Comment: Oh Thanks. I will try the perf tool

Answer (score 0):

Profiling works with the gold and LLD linkers. [This error is caused only when using the BFD linker](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24857). The `sh_info` entry for `.dynsym` section should point to the first non-LOCAL symbol but in the error case, it is set too low.

To verify, run `readelf -aW` on the problematic shared library. In my repo, the `sh_info` for `.dynsym` is 3 whereas there are at least 11 LOCAL symbols.